# What's the equivalent for update_attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Normally, when I add a new product to an @announcement, I do:

```
@announcement = Announcement.find(params[:id])
@announcement.products << Product.find_all_by_id(params[:announcement_products])
```

What's the equivalent of doing `@announcement.products << Product.find_all_by_id(params[:announcement_products])` for `update_attributes()`?

As a reference, my model definition looks like:

**MODEL**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :announcement_products
  has_many :announcements, :through => :announcement_products

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :announcements#, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Announcement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :announcement_products
  has_many :products, :through => :announcement_products

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products#, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end

class AnnouncementProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :announcement
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. In your example you're assigning the has_many relationship, but you're question seems to be about updating the attributes of that relationship. Can you better describe the inputs and expected outcomes?

Comment: Basically, an Announcement can have many Products. Lets say I have 3 products and Announcement.first has the first 2 products assigned to it. I would like to be able to add third third product to Announcement.first. That's what I am trying to do

Comment: Assuming you want to update the set of products attached to the announcement, will `@announcement.products = Product.find_all_by_id(params[:announcement_products])` not do the trick? What am I missing?

Comment: @announcement.products = Product.find_all_by_id(params[:announcement_products]) will add the record to the database before the method update_attributes() is called. If I have validations, which check for unique products per announcement, then the validation will trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set :product_ids in the params for attachment.  So

```
{:announcement=>{:name=>"foo222", :description=>"bar", :product_ids => [8, 9]}}
```

is what you are looking for.  This can be achieved with checkboxes or anything else that sends an "array" in the http request.

Also, if you're using attr_accessible, don't forget to add the product_ids attribute to the list, just remember to look out for mass assignment if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

Look up the association methods that has_many gives you.  Among them are "association_ids=", which expects an array of ids.  This works well with update_attributes, because if you do this

```
params = {:product => {:announcement_ids => [1,2,3]}}
@product.update_attributes(params[:product])
```

that effectively does

```
@product.announcement_ids = [1,2,3]
```

This works well with checkboxes in a form, writing announcement ids to "product[announcement][]" for example.

Comment: Hmm in console, I tried: params = {:announcement=>{:name=>"foo111", :description=>"bar", :products => {:product_ids => [8,9,10]}}}; Announcement.find(37).update_attributes!(params[:announcement]). The announcement record (for name and description) changes. However, no new records are added on the AnnouncementProduct model (announcement_products table). Anything that I am missing?